# Is my assumption about sentence structure correct?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

SEO is one of the keys to unlock traffic for your ecommerce store.

Background: This is from a piece I am editing. I think the structure is wrong and the proper form should be:

SEO is one of the keys of unlocking traffic for your ecommerce store.

Comment: Why have you put *UNLOCK* in twice?

Comment: I suggest, "SEO is one of the keys to unlocking traffic for your e-commerce store." I have no idea why SEO is a "key" or why traffic would be "locked." However, I assume this is an industry-specific comment, and that your intended reader would understand it. Also, it seems to beg the question, what are the other keys?

Answer (score 0):

Both phrasings sound awkward to me. It may be more clear to readers if it's written as

> SEO is one of the key *tactics* used to unlock traffic to your ecommerce store.

I tried to preserve the original form of the sentence as much as possible, though I would revisit the usage of *unlock* in this example. In the case that this is not an industry standard term that I am not aware of, there are wordings which convey this idea better.